# How can I keep the structure of a variable in R?

Tags: r, function, structure

I have a data frame and a function. I when I run a function with the data frame as an argument, somehow it seems it changes the structure.
So I am getting errors.
I pasted the code and the data frame I am working on.
The error I am getting is "Error in plot[row, 1] : incorrect number of dimensions"
Code

```
avg.value = function(plot,delta,row) {
  #plot=deparse(substitute(plot))
  #delta=Week1DeltaT
  value=as.numeric()
  avg.value=as.numeric()
  for (row in 1:11) {
  # compute firtst value separately
  value[1]=plot[row,1]*delta[1]
  value[1]
  # Loop for rest of the values 
  i=1
  end = length(delta)-1
  end
  for( i in 1:end) {
    value[i+1]=(plot[row,i+1]-plot[row,i])*delta[i+1]
    i=i+1
  }
  avg.value[row]=sum(value)/4
  }
  return(avg.value)
}
```

Variable(data frame)
      plot

```
    6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
R1  3 3 4 4  4  4  4  4
R2  1 3 3 3  3  4  4  4
R3  1 1 3 4  4  4  4  4
R4  1 3 4 4  4  4  4  4
R5  3 4 4 4  4  4  4  4
R6  1 3 3 4  4  4  4  4
R7  1 2 2 3  3  4  4  4
R8  2 4 4 4  4  4  4  4
R9  1 2 2 4  4  4  4  4
R10 3 4 4 4  4  4  4  4
R11 1 1 4 4  4  4  4  4
```

delta(a numeric vector of length 8)

```
6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13
```

row(a single numeric value. It can be from 1 to 11)

```
1~11, numeric
```

I realized from the comment that I accidentally begin the loop from the wrong place. Now this function works as I wanted.

Comment: what is delta? can you dput your data.frame?

Comment: You should also show what code you use to run your function (and which produces the error), plus the error message that you receive. For example, your function has a `row` argument that isn't actually usable because it's immediately overwritten in the function body by the for loop.

Comment: you create `avg.value ` as a vector and you return `avg.value ` as a vector. I'm not sure what more you are expecting

Comment: The problem is solved. Thank you all for the comments.